# Manage startActivityForResult and onActivityResult

Tags: android

I'm having difficulties in achieving something that is important for my application and it's managing onActivityResult.

For example i have 3 activities.

**Activity A** which needs to get callback from other two activities and which runs method `startActivityForResult()`

**Activity B** which needs to return some value to Activity A, but also in some case needs to start Activity C and finish also.

**Activity C** is called from Activity B, but i need to return values to Activity A

So my question is, is it possible somehow to `startActivityForResult()` from Activity B, and it refers on Activity A, or any other suggestion would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- **A** calls **B** via `startActivityForResult()`.
- **B** does its work. When it's done are 2 possibilities:

  1. **B** finishes its work and sends its result to **A** by calling `setResult()` and `finish()`
  2. **B** calls `startActivityForResult()` on **C**.
- Now when **C** is done, you send your result to **B** by calling `setResult()` and `finish()`.
- **B** gets the result in its `onActivityResult()` and can now pass it to **A** by calling *again* `setResult()` and `finish()`.

I hope this was understandable. If you need further clarification, please comment.

Comment: I guess i would need to escape finishing Activity B when i'm calling `startActivityForResult()` on Activity C?

Comment: No, actually you are just sending your result back. When you're done in C, you can send the result to B and from there send it to A.